# Haml::SyntaxError: Invalid attribute list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to interpolate a ruby variable in a HAML`%img` src tag, with the ruby interpolation operator `#{}`. In the following way:

```
 -@locations.each do |location|
  %li
    %img(src: "#{location.thumbnail_url}")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Invalid attribute list: "(src: \"\#{location.thumbnail_url}\")".
```

Is there a valid way to do this? I am sure it has been done before but can't see any literature/any other posts about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you’re mixing the two attribute styles, the [normal style](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attributes_) and the [HTML style](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#htmlstyle_attributes_).

You want to either replace `()` with `{}` and use the normal style:

```
%img{src: "#{location.thumbnail_url}"}
```

or use the HTML style with `=` instead of `:`, like this:

```
%img(src = "#{location.thumbnail_url}")
```

Comment: @Thalatta with "normal" ruby hash attributes you can do without the string interpolation `%img{src: location.thumbnail_url}`